# Rails 3: Controller params default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, parameters

I am using a remote form_for for my show action to retrieve content based on the params passed by this form.

```
= form_tag  modelname_path(@modelname), :id=>"select_content_form", :remote => true, :method => 'get' do               
  = text_field_tag :content_type, params[:content_type], :id=>"select_content_type"
  = submit_tag "submit", :name => nil, :id=>"select_content_submit"
```

And I alter the content in controller as follows:

```
# Default params to "type1" for initial load
if params[:content_type]
  @content_type = params[:content_type];
else
  @content_type = "type1"
end

case @content_type

when "type1"
  # get the content
  @model_content = ...

when "type1"
  # get the content
  @model_content = ...
```

My question is, whether the above approach is the only we can set defaults for params or can we do it in a better manner. This works but I would like to know if this is the right approach.

**UPDATE**
Based on the suggestion below, I used the following and got an error on defaults.merge line:

```
defaults = {:content_type=>"type1"}
params = defaults.merge(params)
@content_type = params[:content_type]
```

Comment: For anyone still wondering how to do this in rails. Please use `params.reverse_merge({ my_param: "test"})`.

It will use the default params and merge it together with controller params.

Comment: The `reverse_merge` suggested above now has an alias `with_defaults` so that code reads a bit nicer: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Parameters/with_defaults and https://gorails.com/episodes/rails-parameters-with_defaults

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A good way of setting default options is to have them in a hash, and merge your incoming options onto it. In the code below, `defaults.merge(params)` will overwrite any values from the params hash over the default ones.

```
def controller_method
    defaults = {:content=>"Default Content", :content_type=>"type1"}
    params = defaults.merge(params)
    # now any blank params have default values

    @content_type = params[:content_type]
    case @content_type
        when "type1"
            @model_content = "Type One Content"
        when "type2"
            #etc etc etc
    end
end
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. However, it gives me the following error:
*can't convert nil into Hash*

Comment: does it throw that for defaults.merge?

Comment: Ok, is the above code sitting inside a controller method like my example code? If not, params will be nil. If you're testing this in the console, you can just set params to be a hash full of hypothetic options

Comment: Huh. weird. Well then you could put something in there like params||= {} to get rid of the error

Comment: Deprecated in Rails 5 since `params` is no longer a `Hash`.

Answer (score 7):

If there is a static list of types you could make it a dropdown box and just don't include a blank option so that something is always selected. But if you're stuck with a textbox you could clean up the controller action by using a before filter:

```
class FoosController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_content_type, :only => [:foo_action]

  def foo_action
    ...
  end

  protected

     def set_content_type
       params[:content_type] ||= "type1"
     end
end
```

Comment: Doesn't work for nested parameters. For example, `params[:outer][:inner] ||= 'value'` won't work if `params` does not have key `:outer`. A possible (but verbose) work-around is `params[:outer] ||= {inner: 'value'}; params[:outer][:inner] ||= 'value'`

Comment: Oh this works: `params[:outer] ||= {}; params[:outer][:inner] ||= 'value'`

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add to this discussion a working way to set default params:

```
defaults = { foo: 'a', bar: 'b' }
params.replace(defaults.merge(params))
```

This avoids assigning a local variable via "params =".